# aws fallback option while fargate is scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-fargate

Given that fargate takes a little while to spinup a new healthy container that takes requests, **what's the best way to handle sudden spikes in traffic that require additional processing power**?

I was thinking of using lambda as a fallback, BUT I haven't seen this mentioned as a "design pattern" anywhere AND for this to work every request would have to additionally go through a Step Function or something (?) that will switch to lambda - which cost wise might be really heavy.

Comment: So you're going to somehow wrap your current web server application in a Lambda handler to be able to deploy it on Lambda? Lambda doesn't run regular docker images, it requires the images conform to the Lambda runtime interface. Also, how are you going to configure your Load Balancer to route your "fallback" requests to a different Target Group?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The webapp is comprised of microservices that could be run either on fargate OR on lambda. Given that fargate seems cheaper, I'd like to run it there AND if I have a sudden BIG spike in traffic, I'd like to handle that extra traffic somehow until fargate scales up (that's my question: how to handle that extra traffic until fargate scales-up) -> I was thinking if lambda could handle the extra traffic until fargate scales

Comment: Are you sure Fargate is cheaper? Fargate will charge for your service running 24/7, while Lambda will only charge for the time it takes to process a request. In any case, it still leaves the question of how you would configure your load balancer to handle a hybrid ECS/Lambda environment. That usually only works when ECS and Lambda are serving different paths of your website. I'd love to know how to make the load balancer balance the same traffic across both. Is there some sort of secondary target group configuration I'm not aware of?

Comment: When you get constant hits, fargate is cheaper ([see also here](https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/06/17/aws-cost-analysis-comparing-lambda-ec2-fargate/)). But when a sudden big spike comes, I saw that fargate takes some minutes to spinup a container and register it with the load balancer - is there nothing that could be done in this case except say "Please wait, we're scaling?" :-)
P.S.: I'll look into this hybrid ECS/Lambda option and report back here

Comment: Large companies would simply overprovision their resources so they could handle the beginning of a spike while new resources were being provisioned. Smaller, cost-conscious companies would have a slow, laggy website for a few minutes until more resources are provisioned. If fargate (ECS) is taking minutes to deploy your task then your docker image is probably really big. The larger the image the longer it takes to provision. I have small Alpine images that provision very quickly, and large Ubuntu based images that take a few minutes.

Comment: "Overprovisioning" is a valid/helpful answer IMO and I'll accept it if you submit it and no other answer is provided. I was thinking I'm missing something, but apparently that's how it is. Thank you!

Comment: Overprovisioning isn't a very good answer. I'm genuinely curious if there's a way to split some of the traffic on the load balancer between ECS and Lambda. I thought maybe you knew something I didn't regarding that. Maybe someone will come along and post an answer that shows how to do that.

Comment: Of course you should also be using caching on your backend for things like database queries via something like Redis, and caching HTTP and API responses at the edge, via a CDN.  Unless your app/service is very write-heavy, that is usually enough to handle most traffic spikes.